# Adding/removing/editing an item within a wizard. What happens when I cancel item

Tags: usability, workflow, wizard, design-process

I have one UX challenge. I have one layout, it isn't wizard, but it works like wizard. So we have flow. First you select one item, then you must click to edit this item, and then you can reorder/add/edit/remove subitems inside this item. The subitems can be visible in other layout, so they do not depend on main items.

I have question for you, what happens with subitems if I add, or edit subitems, and then I Cancel editing for main item? I save subitems? Or I cancel them? Ok if I save what I have added or edited, that's fine. I think, that if I create subitem inside item, and then cancel main item, then subitem stays created.

I hope that you have some ideas. Thank you for your help!

So we have:

1. ITEM 1

   - subitem 1
   - subitem 2
   - subitem 3
2. ITEM 2

   - subitem 1
   - subitem 2
   - ...
3. ITEM 3

   - subitem 1
   - ...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ever you add an item and then when you are going to edit an item, we should have prompt message for save are cancel the added item.

same message should be displayed once we have edited the sub item too.

there should be final save button to the whole process then user can understand its the final call for the form.

this is my view.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Yes I have Save button at the end of "wizard". I can't post more images, because of my reputation, so I posted only two main images. Ok I agree with prompt messages, I have this already designed, but I thought that maybe is better solution.

Comment: Thanks, as per the back end developer view you have to cut down the process in to step wise so that it will be good in performance and usability too.